# Extracting future in Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Consider the below code:

```
class TestActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {

    case "hello" => 
      sender ! Future {
        "Sample future result"
      }
  }
}
```

I have the below route defined:

```
def r5: Route = {
    pathPrefix("check") {
      onSuccess(system.actorOf(Props[TestActor]).ask("hello")) {
        successResult =>
          complete {
            "The result is " + successResult
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

When I access the route, I get the output as `The result is Success(Sample future result)` while I expected it to be `The result is Sample future result`. From the docs [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onSuccess.html) about onSuccess:

> Evaluates its parameter of type Future[T], and once the Future has
>   been completed successfully, extracts its result as a value of type T
>   and passes it to the inner route.

and the example given is:

```
val route =
  path("success") {
    onSuccess(Future { "Ok" }) { extraction =>
      complete(extraction)
    }
  }
```

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ask` returns a `Future[T]`. Your pattern match handler inside `receive` wraps it in an additional `Future[T]`, so you're getting a `Future[Future[String]]`.

If you want to only retrieve `T`, remove the `Future` from your `TestActor`:

```
case class TestResult(s: String)
case "hello" => 
  sender ! TestResult("Sample future result")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the use of ask is inevitable then in the onComplete in r5 route you need to open the future twice as you are receiving a Future[Future[String]].

The on Complete will unwrap one and you can have

```html
  def r5: Route = {
    pathPrefix("check") {
      onSuccess(system.actorOf(Props[TestActor]).ask("hello")) {
        successResult => { 
                 successResult.Oncomplete {
                      case Success(res) => {
                                complete {
                                      "The result is " + res //res will have Sample Future Result }
                      case Failure(ex) => complete("Some Error Occured")
        
      }
    }
  }
```